# Fibre card to switch (mini-Gbic)

Tags: networking, hardware, fiber

I have a server with a fibre card in it which I want to connect to my 24 port procurve switch.  The 10G 2 port fibre card supports fiber transceivers supporting SR, LR, LRM.  The switch has two ports that can either be used as a RJ-45 10/100/1000 port or used as a open mini-GBIC slot.  My question then is what do I need to get in order to connect the card to the switch?  Do I need a mini-GBIC transceiver and fibre cable?  If so what exactly should I look for?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways you could do this.

One would be to get, as you suggested, a mini-GBIC transceiver module and fibre cable. You would need to be sure that the module is compatible with the switch (I'm afraid I can't be more specific than that, as my experience with mini-GBIC is somewhat limited) and the fibre card (make sure it supports at least one of the same [modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10-gigabit_Ethernet) as the fibre card)

The other solution would be to get a stand alone fibre media converter. Selecting the converter would be similar to selecting the mini-GBIC module, however you shouldn't have to worry about the compatibility with the switch. This would also require the correct fibre cable as well. Then run a normal ethernet cable to the switch.
Note that if the fibre is 10 gbps and the the ethernet is only 1 gbps (or less) that this method would make a bottle neck for your network. If the server is not heavily used, that might not matter.

As for the cable, there are a number of different connector types available for fibre, so you'd need to make sure you get the correct one. The specifications for your network card and mini-GBIC module / media converter should indicate the connector type. There are also fibre cables available with one type of connector on one end, and a *different* connector on the other end. This allows for devices using different connectors to link together.